# A question about how to deploy my sprinboot web application to tomcat8

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, tomcat

I had a problem accessing the JSP file when I started the jar package with java-jar, but when I started the springboot project locally with the IDE IDEA, I couldn't access the JSP file, why?When I started in tomcat8,it cannot be accessed too.

Sorry, I update it in [I have an problem about how to run a springboot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926080/i-have-an-problem-about-how-to-run-a-springboot-project).

Comment: Apologize my poor English.

Comment: it's tough to understand ur queries...access file means what ?

Comment: @this_is_om_vm just 404 in chrome

Comment: obviously so what you want ?did u want your jsp to load directly in browser?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy spring boot application in tomcat(Here you need to notice that spring boot evolves use of embedded tomcat) so you do not require to put manually jar in any tomcat folder  .The best approach is run the below maven commands.

> mvn clean package

As it successfully execute the maven command it will create a target folder in your webapp you will get a jar file in your target folder.

Now only you want to run your jar using command prompt

> java -jar namefJar.jar

Now you will see your spring boot app will be working fine.

Comment: what's the difference between tomcat and "java -jar xx.jar"

Comment: Implicit deployement of jar in embedded tomcat is supported in spring boot by default if you are running your web application.

Comment: I use ClassLoader.getSystemResource("").getPath() to get resourece path, if I use  IDEA and run,it works,but if I use java -jar,it doestn't work and throw NPE

Comment: I want to get an excel file under resource path

Comment: can you please update your question with your code .What you actually want to achieve it's not understandable.

Comment: OK,I update my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926080/i-have-an-problem-about-how-to-run-a-springboot-project, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Once i had a similar problem and when i add the below dependency, it got fixed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I use <scope>provided</scope> but it doesn't work, why?