# I have an problem about how to run a springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

In my web application, I want to **read an excel file** which is in src/main/resource/static/doc, so I use

`String basePath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("").getPath();`

to get the resource path and read it. It was worked in my IDE IDEA, I just run it and can get the excel.

However, When I use `java -jar lab.jar` to run a spring boot project, it threw a NullpointerException, but when I use

`String basePath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("application.properties").getPath();`

and print it, I saw /Users/zhangzhikai/lab-center/target/lab.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties.

**Why can't I get the excel from the jar?**

Here is my file dirctionary:
[image]

Comment: use this directly File file = new ClassPathResource("/doc/modal/model.xls").getFile();

Comment: Because there isn't such a thing when packaged as a JAR. The solution from @this_is_om_vm won't work either because there isn't a `File` pointing to that resource in a packaged application. Instead just use the `ClassPathResource` to read the `InputStream` instead of a `File`.

Comment: @this_is_om_vm I want to read modal.xls and create new file new.xls to doc/temp,can I get the doc path?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your reply.Can you help me write the code?I quite do not understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `File` in Java it has to point to a physical file on the OS file system. This is the case when running an unpackaged application, however when running a `jar` it isn’t a physical file and as such won’t work (resulting in errors or null pointer exception)

Use one of the `Resource` classes of Spring to access the resource. In this case, as it comes from the classpath you want to use a `ClassPathResource`. Then directly use the `InputStream` to read the file.

```
Resource input = new ClassPathResource(“static/doc/modal/model.xls”);
InputStream in = input.getInputStream();
// Use InputStream to read file
```

This will work as packaged and unpackaged application. Don’t use `getFile` as that won’t work when packaged.

Comment: This worked for me to reference an image in Spring Boot with Open PDF (pdf library)  + Elastic Beanstalk. After i got the input i am doing the following `Image.getInstance(input.getURI().toString());`

Answer (score -1):

```
    File xlsfile = new ClassPathResource("/doc/modal/model.xls").getFile();
     //also check the path
    //String currentPath = xlsfile .getAbsolutePath(); 
    File newXls=new File("classpath:static/doc/temp");
    newXls=xlsfile;
```

As discuss in comment hope this might help you .

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [doc/modal/model.xls] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: sorry you need to replace it with File xlsFile= new File("classpath:static/doc/modal/model.xls");

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it does work,and if I want to create a new excel,just new File("classpath:static/doc/temp/new.xls") ? but it's not exist.

Comment: use simply File("classpath:static/doc/temp/new")  ...don't append file extension

Comment: That won’t work, as first it isn’t a file resource when packaged as an archive, and `File` doesn’t understand `classpath:` as a prefix as that is Spring specific.

Comment: then use File("classpath:static/doc/temp/new.xls")